# start x11 session in schroot beside the standard x11 session

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, x11, isolation, schroot

I recently started development with **Python 3** and opencv. Since **opencv** has to compiled manually to get Python 3 support I created a separate development environment using **schroot** which is pretty helpful to try out building libs without messing up the host system along the process. 
As long as the build-tools stay inside the chroot'ed shell everything works as expected. But when I start an x11 application like **Pycharm** inside the chroot environment it gains access to everything (i guess because it's using the x11 session of the host system). How to keep my development environment completely isolated?

- Can I start a second but isolated x11 session just for my **IDE**?
- Did I miss some configuration options? (i use minimal schroot profile + pts mounted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. #### You could use `XNest` or `Xephyr` a xserver in a window,

   First you have to create some authorization file:

   ```
   touch $HOME/.Xephyr_auth_1
   Xephyr -auth $HOME/.Xephyr_auth_1_1 :1 &
   xpid=$!
   xauth -f $HOME/.Xephyr_auth_1 generate :1 . trusted
   kill $xpid
   ```

   Then run your server with apropriated options...

   ```
   Xephyr -auth $HOME/.Xephyr_auth_1 -screen 1280x800 :1 &
   xpid=$!
   DISPLAY=:1 XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xephyr_auth_1 metacity &
   DISPLAY=:1 XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xephyr_auth_1 firefox -profileManager -fullscreen
   ```

   Once done:

   ```
   kill $! $xpid
   ```
2. #### You could use `chvt` command to access another TTY and run another session

   1. From user's screen menu, go to *change user* and run another session
   2. By using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> with *`Fn`* = <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>, or use one of `sudo chvt 1` to `sudo chvt 6`, to switch to another tty, then log:

      ```
      Login: user
      password: 
      startx -- :1
      ```